# accessing tags in the code always yields undefined

Tags: cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

According to the [docs from @badeball](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/tags.md) one can access the tags used in `.feature` files from within the code using the Cypress environment variable `tags` or `TAGS`.

Example for a tag: `@TEST_FOO-42`

However I only get empty log lines for:

```
cy.log(Cypress.env('tags'));
cy.log(Cypress.env('TAGS'));
```

And

```
cy.log(typeof Cypress.env('tags'));
cy.log(typeof Cypress.env('TAGS'));
```

Yields `undefined`. What do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is not possible. Cypress.env('tags') does not access the tags of a test but instead yields the runtime `tags` argument as in `cypress run -e tags='@foo and @bar'`. See also:

https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/774#issuecomment-1193914180